# Cannot truncate tables consistently

Tags: cassandra

I have a two node Cluster that I am using for testing programs, what I do is trucating a table everytime I run my program and then inserting some datas at the end of it.

The thing is, when I perform too much truncates in a day, I am getting timeout exceptions, unlike selecting and inserting datas wich works fine.

I tried to drop my keyspace and recreating it but the problem appears after a few runs, I can't figure out how to make my cluster "Stable", sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Here's how my `nodetool status` looks like :

[image]

And here's the TRACING :

```
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=host
Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try to activate query tracing when you perform the TRUNCATE to chase down the issue. Is there any exception in the /var/log/cassandra/system.log file that could be related to the truncate operation ?

Comment: I am using the Scala driver, I don't think it is possible to retrieve request tracing is it? I looked in my system.log to see if anything went wrong and I didn't saw any excpetions ...

Comment: Each truncate is performing snapshot as well which creates backup of data (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/truncate_r.html). Might be that is causing problems?  You can switch off that functionality in `cassandra.yml` by setting `auto_snapshot` to off.

Comment: It might be the cause, In my /data/keyspace/table folders there is indeed a lot of snapshots. I will use this parameter for now on and see if there is any improvements

Comment: @Will Did it help? Are you not getting timeout error after changing `auto_snapshot` settings?